# Xcode 9.4.1 is not showing function callers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift4, xcode9.4

I couldn't find callers of any method ever since i started using Xcode 9.4.1 .
Can somebody find me a fix for this, since i'm wasting so much time to find its callers by copy-paste method name and search.

[image]

Comment: They are dynamic and contextually bound to where your cursor is. So, try to set your cursor inside the body of a method for example and hopefully, they should be working fine...

Comment: @Alladinian Thanx , that I already know.they're not working fine.